# How import modules in python

Tags: python, import

[image]

I am in handlerds.py
I need to import the `User` class from the `models.py` file.
Relative file paths:

- `jujaorda/app/models.py`
- `jujaorda/telegram/handlers.py`

I tried the following import statement:
`from jujaorda.app.models import User`

But it didn't work, and I received the following error:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jujaorda'"

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/Users/saveliymiheev/Desktop/Python/jujaorda/jujaorda/telegram/handlers.py", line 4, in <module>`
`from jujaorda.app.models import User`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jujaorda'`

Comment: The only question is, does your search path (`sys.path`) contain the directory that immediately contains `jujaorda`?